# add SOAP headers to CXF when using stubs generarted by wsdl2java

Tags: java, header, cxf

I'm trying to write a webservice client. I generated java stubs from a wsdl using CXF 3.2 wsdl2java. I've tried several methods from here and other google searches to add a header to my outgoing soap request, but sofar have not been able to get it to work. I feel like I'm missing something simple, like it shouldn't be that complicated to add a header using CXF, but I guess I don't know.

Here's is the full java code for the client:

```
public class sforceClient {

  private static QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("urn:partner.soap.sforce.com", "SforceService");
  private static String serverURL;
  private static String sessionId = "";
  private static String theQuery;
  private static File wsdlFile;
  private static URL wsdlURL;

  public sforceClient() {
//Setup code to log output to terminal
      System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
      System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
      System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
      System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
  }

  public static Object callQuery()
  {
//Validate wsdl file
    try {
      wsdlFile = new File(theWsdl);
      if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
        wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
      } else {
        wsdlURL = new URL(theWsdl);
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
      mue.printStackTrace();
    }

//Instantiate stubs from wsdl2java
    SforceService ss = new SforceService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    Soap port = ss.getSoap();
    LoginResult resp;

    try {
      if ("".equals(sessionId)) { //SessionId is not set, login to the server and set the values
        resp = port.login(userName,password+securityToken);
        serverURL = resp.getServerUrl();
        sessionId = resp.getSessionId();
      }
      BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
//Add SessionHeader tag 
      List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
      SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
      SOAPElement authElement = sf.createElement(new QName("urn:partner.soap.sforce.com", "SessionHeader"));
//Add sessionId to SessionHeader
      SOAPElement tokenElement = authElement.addChildElement("sessionId");
      tokenElement.addTextNode(sessionId);
      SoapHeader tokenHeader = new SoapHeader(new QName("urn:partner.soap.sforce.com", "SessionHeader"), authElement);
//Add header to headers list
      headers.add(tokenHeader);
      bp.getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
//Change the endpoint url to correct API url. Provided from response to login request
      bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, serverURL);
//Get the result from the query request
      QueryResult qResult= port.query(theQuery);
      return qResult;
    } catch (LoginFault lf) {
      lf.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidIdFault iif) {
      iif.printStackTrace();      
    } catch (UnexpectedErrorFault uef) {
      uef.printStackTrace();      
    } catch (MalformedQueryFault mqf) {
      mqf.printStackTrace();      
    } catch (InvalidQueryLocatorFault iqlf) {
      iqlf.printStackTrace();      
    } catch (InvalidFieldFault iff) {
      iff.printStackTrace();      
    } catch (InvalidSObjectFault isof) {
      isof.printStackTrace();     
    } catch (SOAPException jbe) {
      jbe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

    public static void setUserName(String userName) {
        sforceClient.userName = userName;
    }

    public static String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public static void setPassword(String password) {
        sforceClient.password = password;
    }

    public static String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public static void setSecurityToken(String securityToken) {
        sforceClient.securityToken = securityToken;
    }

    public static String getSecurityToken() {
        return securityToken;
    }

    public static void setTheWsdl(String theWsdl) {
        sforceClient.theWsdl = theWsdl;
    }

    public static String getTheWsdl() {
        return theWsdl;
    }

    public static void setTheQuery(String theQuery) {
        sforceClient.theQuery = theQuery;
    }

    public static String getTheQuery() {
        return theQuery;
    }

    public static void setServerURL(String serverURL) {
        sforceClient.serverURL = serverURL;
    }

    public static String getServerURL() {
        return serverURL;
    }

    public static void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        sforceClient.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public static String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }
}
```

I'm looking for it to produce this soap request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>MYSESSIONID</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:query>
         <urn:queryString>SELECT AMOUNT, ID, LEADSOURCE, NAME, OWNERID, PRICEBOOK2ID, STAGENAME, TYPE, ACCOUNTID  FROM OPPORTUNITY</urn:queryString>
      </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:query xmlns:ns3="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns2="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com">
<ns2:queryString>SELECT AMOUNT, ID, LEADSOURCE, NAME, OWNERID, PRICEBOOK2ID, STAGENAME, TYPE, ACCOUNTID  FROM OPPORTUNITY</ns2:queryString>
</ns2:query>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```